# Foreign key for inherited table in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, inheritance

I have tables `animals` and `water` inherited from `targets` table. They look like this:

targets

```sql
create table targets
(
    id   integer not null
        primary key,
    name text
);
```

animals (water table is the same)

```sql
create table animals
(
    type_id  integer,
    flock_id integer,
    primary key (id)
)
    inherits (targets);
```

Also I have a `actions` table which has a foreign key `target_id`.

actions

```sql
create table actions
(
    id        integer not null
        primary key,
    target_id integer
        references targets(id),
);
```

I have some rows in `animals` and `water` tables. And I am trying to insert new row into `actions` table with `target_id` equals to id of some animal.

```sql
INSERT INTO actions (id, target_id)
VALUES (1, 4);
```

But I receive an error:

> [23503] ERROR: insert or update on table "actions" violates foreign key constraint "actions_target_id_fkey"
> Key (target_id)=(4) is not present in table "targets".

Maybe I don't understand the table's inheritance, but how can I do my task correctly (`target_id` should be a foreign key for `water` and `animals` tables at the same time)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I hope this might wrork , you have two tables, animals and water, that inherit from a parent table, targets. You want to create a foreign key in a different table that can reference both the animals and water tables using the id columnn of the targets table.

for that, you can create a foreign key that references the id column of the targets table and use a `CHECK` constraint to ensure that the referenced row is in either the animals or water table

```
CREATE TABLE some_table (
id serial primary key,
target_id integer references targets(id),
-- other columns
CONSTRAINT target_id_animals_water_check CHECK (
    target_id IN (SELECT id FROM animals)
    OR target_id IN (SELECT id FROM water)
)
```

);

`some_table` is the name of the table that you want to create the foreign key in, and `target_id` is the name of the column that will store the foreign key. The references clause specifies that the `target_id` column should reference the id column of the targets table.

The `CHECK` constraint ensures that the referenced row is in either the animals or water table. The IN operator is used to check if the `target_id` is in the set of id values in either the animals or water table.

With this setup, you can insert rows into the animals and water tables as well as the `some_table` table, and the foreign key constraint will ensure that only valid references are allowed and you can insert a row into the `some_table` table like this
INSERT INTO some_table (target_id) VALUES (1);

Comment: Unfortunately, I got error: `[0A000] ERROR: cannot use subquery in check constraint`

Comment: another way you could use is to create a separate table that lists all valid `target IDs` from the `animals` and `water` tables, and use that table in a foreign key constraint for the `target_id` column in the `some_table`` table.This creates a new table with a single id column, and populates it with all the valid target IDs from the `animals` and `water` tables.

Then, you can use this table in a foreign key constraint for the target_id column in the `some_table` table

Comment: ALTER TABLE some_table
ADD CONSTRAINT some_table_target_id_fkey
FOREIGN KEY (target_id)
REFERENCES valid_targets (id); here valid target means the new table and This foreign key constraint ensures that the target_id column in the some_table table can only reference valid target IDs from the animals and water tables

Comment: Ok, I think this is a solution, thanks. Will you create an answer with this info or it can be left here in comments?

Comment: i will create another one,so that others can view that easily